# How to create column that would aggregate data for each quarter in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m, powerbi-desktop

The problem is that end user wants to Export data to excel from matrix   and view all columns in a dataset.

But if I create a measure and throw it into a visual and then "Export Data" - 
only brings 3 columns.

```
RunningTotal_QtrLoss = 
    CALCULATE( 
    SUM(fact_Losses[PaymentAmount]),
    FILTER(ALL(fact_Losses[DevQtr]),fact_Losses[DevQtr]<=MAX(fact_Losses[DevQtr])))
```

[image]

[image]

So I am trying to avoid using `measure` in Power BI in order to be able viewing all columns when export to excel.

For that I calculated RunningTotal in SQL.  But then when I used it in a matrix - it summarized value. I am not sure how to make in not summarize.

In order to solve that I want to try to create column (not measure) in Power BI, and hopefully it will let me extract raw data with all columns.
--==============================================================

How can I simply create a custom column (from Edit Query)  `Sum_Qtr` that would give me the `sum(Premium)` for Quarter and Year?

[image]

Comment: Does it have to have the zeroes or can the sum be repeated?

Answer (score 0):

one way .. put in a total for all instances, then use if to replace most of them with nulls based on adjacent row

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
TotalAmountAdded = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Total Amount",(i) => List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Year] = i[Year] and [Quarter] = i[Quarter]))[Premium]), type number),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(TotalAmountAdded, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Sum_Qtr", each if [Index] = 0 then [Total Amount] else if Source{[Index]}[Quarter]=Source{[Index]-1}[Quarter] and Source{[Index]}[Year]=Source{[Index]-1}[Year] then null else [Total Amount]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Total Amount", "Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```